# Get full response in angular with observe: 'response' with other settings

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, http

It works

```
return this.http.post(url, data, {observe: 'response'})
```

But for some reason it doesn't

```
let options = {
  headers: new HttpHeaders().set('Content-Type', "application/json"),
  withCredentials: true,
  observe: 'response'
}
return this.http.post(url, data, options)
```

Why and how i can use observe: 'response' in this case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should tell exactly what's not working. I guess the typescript compiler is complaining about the type.

You can solve this like this: `return this.http.post(url, data, options as any)`